# Python - Simplest method of stripping the last byte from a file?

Tags: python, file, truncate

I want to make a script that will take a file, strip off the last byte of a file. The file can be anything, not just text.

I have been playing around with the seek() and tell() methods, but I can't find a way of dealing with the file that allows me to do this.

I figured it should be relatively trivial, but perhaps Python is not an appropriate tool for this?

```
fileStripped = file[:-4]
newpath = path + "\\" + fileStripped 
if not os.path.exists(newpath): 
 os.makedirs(newpath)
with open(fname, "r") as f:
 f.seek (0, 2)           # Seek @ EOF
 fsize = f.tell()        # Get Size
 f=f.read
 f=f[:fsize-2]
```

This method errors, and tells me I can not subscript the `f=f[:fsize-2]` line

Comment: Do you want to do it in-place or write it to a new file?

Comment: @Jay: The `f=f.read` should be `f=f.read()`. What you're currently asking it to do is subscript the `read` method.

Comment: On unix you can simply do `truncate -s -1 filename`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy the file and then remove the last byte by seeking back one byte and truncating the file:

```
with open(srcfile, 'r') as fsrc:
    with open(destfile, 'w+') as fdest:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fsrc, fdest)
        fdest.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
        fdest.truncate()
```

Comment: Ack, its so easy when you know how! Thank you. This is perfect.

Answer (score 15):

Seek one byte from the end, and truncate.

```
f = open(..., 'r+')
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Comment: That would modify the existing file - he wants to write the truncated data to a new file.

Comment: Well, copying first is easy. And the change is a single byte at the end, so you save nothing doing it the hard way.

Comment: Thank you, this method would work, but I picked TMs as correct as it includes the copying step. I appreciate your time.

Comment: The mode should be `br+`.