# Decrypt file with Python

Tags: python, file, encryption, pycrypto

I am having a problem when decrypting a file that has information appended. The steps I take are the following. I encrypt a file and append a string (converted to bytes) after encryption and write to the file. When I decrypt the file I strip the bytes from the back of the file and proceed to decryption, then I write to the file but the file is corrupted, when I do this same process without appending the bytes it works fine. What could I be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def salsa_encrypt(data):
    cipher = '6d38d2f2d0318e53712156ad06f6813349be934a83b15f723f039a82fa3f2fb9'
    key = bytes.fromhex(cipher)
    nonce_iv = '1c5cd305932039f5'
    nonce = bytes.fromhex(nonce_iv)
    cipher = Salsa20.new(key=key, nonce=nonce)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(data)
    return encrypted


def encrypt():
    string = '50567A8ED6FB1A33F484E62F9280F58F9B7D2DD369F613306970F53331FDBCA41DFF00474529A2BD3DF4A9B9192709B2BF0C890D9D1A746FE61A39CD3F5F28FD89B3303B402D538BF2EE57CCE3B87998BB12B40D35AD1F552F23F7E6599F4BC2FAAE6110033D0EBB70BEF4A5109CB02E1331491E73C4905DBBF51D609A8CFF55B267C5F89EE6D19995C831E26E8D531D107D388133EEC895313F33493C1BE92E73C32509F5BB386B0CFAC216E6DC1C0E36A987F5BF55860FBC43B76EA11DDF036AD3547C8728804CA67E758352587F00094F60CABBCFB4C9D76429DC00000000000000009125B680'
    append = bytes.fromhex(string)
    path_store = os.getcwd() + "\\" + "testing"
    path = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + "testing")
    for file in path:
        print('[*] File - ', file)
        try:
            extension = '.copy'
            fhi = open(path_store + '\\' + file, 'rb')
            fho = open(path_store + '\\' + file + extension, 'wb')
            chunk = fhi.read()
            ciphertext = salsa_encrypt(chunk)
            fho.write(ciphertext + append)
            fhi.close()
            fho.close()
        except Exception:
            print('[-] Could not open: ', file)
            pass
    return
```

And here is the decryption script:

```
def salsa_decrypt(data):
    cipher = 'edd8a9f8e446c41b312649df34f5237740db6b2a5923a5a44300389c9c3d3f54'
    key = bytes.fromhex(cipher)
    nonce_iv = '094f60cabbcfb4c9'
    nonce = bytes.fromhex(nonce_iv)
    cipher = Salsa20.new(key=key, nonce=nonce)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(data)
    return decrypted


def main():
    path_store = os.getcwd() + "\\" + "testing"
    path = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + "testing")
    for file in path:
        print('[*] File - ', file)
        try:
            with open(path_store + '\\' + file, 'rb') as f:
                text = f.read()
                size = len(text)
                chunk = text[:size - 232]
                decrypted = salsa_decrypt(chunk)
                fho = open(path_store + '\\' + 'restored.jpg', 'wb')
                fho.write(decrypted)
                fho.close()
        except Exception:
            print('[-] Could not open: ', file)
            pass
```

UPDATE: I found the solution in another post, I will leave it here in case it helps anybody: [Python - Simplest method of stripping the last byte from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609965/python-simplest-method-of-stripping-the-last-byte-from-a-file)

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting. That would help understanding where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. The problem is that there is no error, it writes to the file without a problem but the image is corrupted. The decryption process is somehow changed as the magic bytes aren't "ffd8ff" which should be for a jpg. Although, if I do it without appending I can open the photo just fine.

Comment: Ok could you check the length of your variable `append`? It seems to me that the decryption function doesn't cut the data in the right place.

Comment: Just did, the length it's 232, I was careful to just cut what I had appended. I have just checked if cutting the bytes without passing them to hex makes a difference, I have opened the file with a hex editor and the last bytes of the file match with those in the hex editor.

Comment: Could it be because you're removing the end-of-file character?

Comment: Not entirely sure but it might have something to do. This answer that I found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609965/python-simplest-method-of-stripping-the-last-byte-from-a-file by ThiefMaster worked perfectly.